# Which is bigger, “a lot” or “a ton”?

Tags: meaning

Maybe there’s no really well-defined answer, but I’m wondering which phrase is the more significant (meaning bigger) between these two:

- We’ve been doing a lot of work.
- We’ve been doing a ton of work.

And even maybe including this one:

- We’ve been doing tons of work.

Comment: You answered your own question in your first sentence.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure, you know.

Comment: A ton is definitely bigger than [a lot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lot_%28unit%29)

Comment: @Paolo Falabella: I disagree - a car that only weighs a ton is nothing to write home about. But if [that's a lot of car in the driveway](http://www.flickr.com/photos/10428495@N05/7394509972/) it probably weighs much more. Anyway, I'm voting to close because it's subjective and Not Constructive (where, for example, would [shedloads of work](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22shedloads+of+work%22&oq=%22shedloads+of+work%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.4826&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) fit on this hypothetical "scale"?). Or *shitloads*, come to that?

Comment: Unless your work is stacking bricks or similar, work cannot be measured in tons.  Whether stacking a ton of bricks is a *lot* depends on whether you are doing it by hand or with the aid of machinery. Without context and without explicit quantification it is impossible to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are interchangeable and used as intensifiers. The emphasis is in the tone. There is no precise quantification intended or even possible in such a statement.

Note that you would say

> We've been doing tons of work.

Not "a tons of work."

Cf. *ass ton*, *shit load*, *shit ton*, etc.

The only way you could establish *a ton* to mean more than *a lot* would be to use it in sequence:

> **Me**: Been working hard lately?
>
> **You**: Yeah, been doing a lot of work.
>
> **Me**: Really? You seem like you have plenty of time for video games.
>
> **You**: Dude, I've been doing a *ton* of work.

But you could easily reverse the two in that exchange and achieve the same effect.

Comment: Of course I understand there's no precise quantification, but, as I understood, "a ton" is usually more significant than "a lot". By the way, thanks for correcting me about "a tons", I fixed that in my question.

Comment: There is no metric that makes "a ton" more than "a lot" — both descriptors are essentially meaningless intensifiers.

Comment: See my addition.

Comment: Ok, I'm convinced.

Comment: @Robusto, although a "metric shitload" would be largest ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use "a ton" over "a lot" to infer a greater quantity or degree of something because, in my mind, a ton is a quantifiably large mass where a "a lot" is very subjective.

Comment: +1, yes, I agree. absolutely compelling evidence, or, more precisely, there is a ton of  evidence on that, but none of it stands up to rigorous indicate what subjective is.

Comment: Rubbish. As @Robusto says, *both descriptors are essentially meaningless intensifiers*. You can have *loads* of work (or *shedloads, shitloads, stacks,* whatever). But it's totally pointless to "rank" them.

Comment: Which is more, a kilo or a lot? Which is less, a bit or a gram?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, it's the perception that a ton is more than a lot that's at play here, certainly not anything quantifiable. My answer is based on how I personally use and rank those two intensifiers.

Comment: @Kristina: I guess it's up to if you want to *use* the words that way. But you should be under no illusion that this meaningfully represents "accurate communication" - again, as Robusto says, you could swap the two terms around in any real-world context, and nobody (except perhaps you) would think there was anything odd going on. There are some "vague" ranking sequences where the vast majority have the same perception (*hideous, ugly, plain, pretty, beautiful, gorgeous*, for example, would normally be thus ranked), but OP's pair really do represent a totally ***subjective*** "beauty contest".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Well, it appears that 50% of those who voted on this question agree with you and 50% agree with me since I got 3 upvotes and 3 downvotes. Lol!

Comment: haha - but we don't know how many of the downvoters are disagreeing with your particular ranking sequence, and how many (like me) are disagreeing with *the concept of "ranking" two such expressions*. Or even simply taking issue with my comment starting *"Rubbish"* (I was feeling a bit tetchy last night, and I sincerely apologise if you felt that was ungentlemanly of me! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, The "rubbish!" made me laugh, so no worries.  I welcome any opportunity to delve into the nuances of English language usage. :-)